# How to sum value of specific key with the same ID inside array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [revenue_generated] => 4.5
                    [month_no] => 1
                    [client_id] => 428
                    [client_name] => Aljazeera pro
                    [company_id] => 18
                    [partner_id] => 18
                    [partner_name] => itialuS India
                    [engagements] => 3
                    [engagementsArr] => 787,925,347
                    [country_id] => 2
                    [country_name] => India
                    [region_code] => S3
                    [region_id] => 3
                    [region_name] => Jamaica
                    [employee_id] => 255
                    [email_id_office] => test@wallpostdev.com
                    [staff_name] => Mark Smith
                    [all_companies_id] => 18,18,18
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [revenue_generated] => 65.4
                    [month_no] => 1
                    [client_id] => 2044
                    [client_name] => Test USA Lead 107
                    [company_id] => 19
                    [partner_id] => 19
                    [partner_name] => Jamaica Activation Partner
                    [engagements] => 1
                    [engagementsArr] => 896
                    [country_id] => 112
                    [country_name] => Jamaica
                    [region_code] => S3
                    [region_id] => 3
                    [region_name] => Jamaica
                    [employee_id] => 273
                    [email_id_office] => smitit2018+747600_273@gmail.com
                    [staff_name] => Raymond Larson
                    [all_companies_id] => 19
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [revenue_generated] => 14.169341894061
                    [month_no] => 2
                    [client_id] => 2046
                    [client_name] => Task
                    [company_id] => 18
                    [partner_id] => 18
                    [partner_name] => itialuS India
                    [engagements] => 1
                    [engagementsArr] => 897
                    [country_id] => 2
                    [country_name] => India
                    [region_code] => S3
                    [region_id] => 3
                    [region_name] => Jamaica
                    [employee_id] => 435
                    [email_id_office] => smitit2018+747600_435@gmail.com
                    [staff_name] => Nithin sabu
                    [all_companies_id] => 18
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [revenue_generated] => 32.4
                    [month_no] => 2
                    [client_id] => 2048
                    [client_name] => Test USA Lead 120
                    [company_id] => 19
                    [partner_id] => 19
                    [partner_name] => Jamaica Activation Partner
                    [engagements] => 1
                    [engagementsArr] => 898
                    [country_id] => 112
                    [country_name] => Jamaica
                    [region_code] => S3
                    [region_id] => 3
                    [region_name] => Jamaica
                    [employee_id] => 275
                    [email_id_office] => smitit2018+747600_275@gmail.com
                    [staff_name] => Jennifer Connelly
                    [all_companies_id] => 19
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [revenue_generated] => 179.01284109149
                    [month_no] => 1
                    [client_id] => 2090
                    [client_name] => Eng.Cancelletion Test1
                    [company_id] => 18
                    [partner_id] => 21
                    [partner_name] => itialuS India Partner
                    [engagements] => 1
                    [engagementsArr] => 910
                    [country_id] => 80
                    [country_name] => India Country
                    [region_code] => A1
                    [region_id] => 4
                    [region_name] => Asia
                    [employee_id] => 255
                    [email_id_office] => test@wallpostdev.com
                    [staff_name] =>  Jhon Smith
                    [all_companies_id] => 18
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [revenue_generated] => 40.01284109149
                    [month_no] => 1
                    [client_id] => 2090
                    [client_name] => Eng.Cancelletion Test1
                    [company_id] => 18
                    [partner_id] => 21
                    [partner_name] => itialuS India Partner
                    [engagements] => 1
                    [engagementsArr] => 910
                    [country_id] => 80
                    [country_name] => India Country
                    [region_code] => A1
                    [region_id] => 4
                    [region_name] => Asia
                    [employee_id] => 255
                    [email_id_office] => test@wallpostdev.com
                    [staff_name] =>  Jhon Smith
                    [all_companies_id] => 18
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [revenue_generated] => 204.7893258427
                    [month_no] => 2
                    [client_id] => 2095
                    [client_name] => TIME TODAY 3
                    [company_id] => 18
                    [partner_id] => 21
                    [partner_name] => itialuS India Partner
                    [engagements] => 1
                    [engagementsArr] => 915
                    [country_id] => 80
                    [country_name] => India Country
                    [region_code] => A1
                    [region_id] => 4
                    [region_name] => Asia
                    [employee_id] => 446
                    [email_id_office] => bala@wall.com
                    [staff_name] => Balaguru Swamy
                    [all_companies_id] => 18
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [revenue_generated] => 65.7893258427
                    [month_no] => 2
                    [client_id] => 2095
                    [client_name] => TIME TODAY 3
                    [company_id] => 18
                    [partner_id] => 21
                    [partner_name] => itialuS India Partner
                    [engagements] => 1
                    [engagementsArr] => 915
                    [country_id] => 80
                    [country_name] => India Country
                    [region_code] => A1
                    [region_id] => 4
                    [region_name] => Asia
                    [employee_id] => 446
                    [email_id_office] => bala@wall.com
                    [staff_name] => Balaguru Swamy
                    [all_companies_id] => 18
                )

        )

)
```

I want output like this:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [revenue_generated] => 69.9
                    [month_no] => 1
                    [engagements] => 4
                    [engagementsArr] => 787,925,347,896
                    [region_code] => S3
                    [region_id] => 3
                    [region_name] => Jamaica
                )

            [1] => Array
               (
                  [revenue_generated] => 46.56
                  [month_no] => 2
                  [engagements] => 2
                  [engagementsArr] => 897,898
                  [region_code] => S3
                  [region_id] => 3
                  [region_name] => Jamaica
               )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                  (
                     [revenue_generated] => 229.02
                     [month_no] => 1
                     [engagements] => 2
                     [engagementsArr] => 910,911
                     [region_code] => A1
                     [region_id] => 4
                     [region_name] => Asia
                  )

            [1] => Array
                  (
                     [revenue_generated] => 270.56
                     [month_no] => 2
                     [engagements] => 2
                     [engagementsArr] => 915,916
                     [region_code] => A1
                     [region_id] => 4
                     [region_name] => Asia
                  )

        )

)
```

I tried in this way but didn't work:

```
    $salesDataArr = [];
    foreach($result as $key => $value) {
        $newkey = 'month_no';
        foreach($value AS $val){
            $salesChartArray[$key]=[];
            if(empty($salesChartArray[$key])) {
                $salesChartArray[$key] = $re;
                $salesChartArray[$key]['month_no'] = $re['month_no'];
                $salesChartArray[$key]['revenue_generated'] = 0;
            }
            $salesChartArray[$key]['engagementsArr'] = $salesChartArray[$key]['engagementsArr'] .','. $re['engagementsArr'];
            $salesChartArray[$key]['all_companies_id'] = $salesChartArray[$key]['all_companies_id'] .','. $re['all_companies_id'];
            $salesChartArray[$key]['engagements'] = $this->countUniqueEngagement($salesChartArray[$key]['engagementsArr']);
            $salesChartArray[$key]['revenue_generated'] += $re['revenue_generated'];

                if(array_key_exists($newkey, $val)){
                    $salesDataArr[$key][$val[$newkey]] = $salesChartArray[$key];
                    $salesDataArr[$key][$val[$newkey]]['engagementsArr'] = $salesChartArray[$key]['engagementsArr'];
                    $salesDataArr[$key][$val[$newkey]]['all_companies_id'] = $salesChartArray[$key]['all_companies_id'];
                    $salesDataArr[$key][$val[$newkey]]['engagements'] = $salesChartArray[$key]['engagements'];
                    $salesDataArr[$key][$val[$newkey]]['revenue_generated'] = $salesChartArray[$key]['revenue_generated'];
                } 
            } 
        }

public function countUniqueEngagement($engagements){
    $exploded = explode(",", $engagements);
    return count(array_filter(array_unique($exploded)));
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please edit your question and show us what you've already tried, where did you get stuck?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have tried like this:

Comment: Please always present your sample input in `var_export()` format so that contributors don't have to reformat your text before starting to code a solution.  If you have ANY relevant columns in your sample data, please remove them -- this is how you craft a [mcve].  There are many questions that demonstrate how to group and sum data.  Please search more. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+arrays+grouping+sum

Answer (score 0):

```
$salesDataArr = array();
$i=0;
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
 if ( $value[$key][$i]['region_code'] == 'S3') {
   $salesDataArr[$key][$i]['region_code'] = 'S3';
    if ( $value[$key][$i]['month_no'] == 1) {
      $salesDataArr[$key][$i]['month_no'] = 1;
    } else if ( $value[$key][$i]['month_no'] == 2) {
      $salesDataArr[$key][$i]['month_no'] = 2;
    }

} else if ( $value[$key][$i]['region_code'] == 'A1') {
   $salesDataArr[$key][$i]['region_code'] = 'A1';
}
 $i++
}
```

that's where you can start

Comment: there would be more months and regions. for each region need to sum revenue_generated amount by month. please check the expected result.

Comment: I just wrote part of the code to guide you. To write a complete loop I would have to have your application on local

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.